# "Performance Density" for a CNN Implementation on FPGA

Tags: fpga

In the paper ["Improving the Performance of OpenCL-based FPGA Accelerator for Convolutional Neural Network"](https://wicil.ece.wisc.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/JZhang_FPGA17_CNN.pdf) at table 6 there is a metric called `Performance Density`. It is defined as `the number of arithmetic operations that one DSP slice executes in one cycle`. There are the values 2.8 respectively 3.06 ops/DSPslice/cycle reported.

When looking at the [Arria 10 DSP](https://www.altera.com/products/fpga/features/dsp/arria10-dsp-block.html) in floating point mode, it can execute one multiplication and one accumulation in one cycle (A*B+C). That means maximum is 2 ops/DSPslice/cycle.

Where is the difference coming from? Did I miss something?

Comment: Each one can perform two independent 18x19bit multiplications. They also have pre-adders.

Comment: That explains the second value, since they use 16 bit fixed point numbers. But the 2.8 ops/DSPslice/cycle are obtained from single precision (32 bit) floating point numbers.